# SQL Agent Job - Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, connection, sql-server-agent

I'm getting this error when running an SSIS package through SQL Agent
Failed to acquire connection "ORACLE ADO.NET". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.

When I log on as the SQL Agent User and run the ssis package directly it is fine. When I then execute it through the SQL agent job, it fails.

I've read around extensively on this topic, and it seems a lot of the advise concerns how you are logged in, configuring of proxy accounts, etc, etc, etc, none of which has been helpful.

I am logging onto an Oracle database with an ADO.NET conncetion. The connection string is as follows (datasource, userid and password have been changed):

Data Source=DATASOURCE;User ID=userid;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;Unicode=True;

I'm loading this from a registry setting using package configuration. To check that I am getting the correct string, I am writing it into a temporary log table. I am definately getting the string I need from the correct registry setting.

I've tested the oracle login credentials though PL/SQL developer, and it lets me login just fine.

As far as I can tell, as I'm using an explicit user name and password for the Oracle connection it just shouldn't matter who the SSIs pacakge is run as. The only point of failure that Ican see would be the reading of the information from the registry, but that seems fine.

I'm really quite baffled, I must confess, and would appreciate any help some of the splendid experts here can offer.

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, tracked this one down after quite a lot of pain.

It was working fine on one environment, but not another, so I fired up Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and ran a package through the SQL Agent job, comparing which system entities were hit on each enviroment.

On the failing environment, at the point of the bulk transfer operation, the package attempted to get the Oracle 11 client DLL, and then hung.

I knew that this was installed, and, moreoever, the DLL path was a system environment setting. After further investigation it was revealed that the server had not been rebooted since the Oracle Client install and the SQL Server Agent process had not bee recycled.

Yes, can you believe it, the old helpdesk fix "Can you reboot your computer?" worked.

Sigh!

Answer (score 1):

We had issues at a client with running packages connecting to Oracle before stored on our sql server instance. The work around we found was to change the package property, protection level, to "Dont save Sensitive Data" and for security purposes, we encrypted the username and password in the package configuration that was decrypted by a udf in sql server. Of course, before you try the whole encryption part, I would recommend putting the username and password in the package configuration without encrypting the values to see if changing the protection level setting is the solution to your specific problem. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Ryan. All my packages were this by default anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when tnsnames.ora file did not have a valid entry for the environment