# Failed to acquire connection. Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection

Tags: sql-server, ssis, distributed-transactions

I am getting following error while attempting to execute the package. I can execute individual task successfully. But whenever attempt to execute whole package it gives me error. 
**SSIS Data flow on distributed transaction - [Execute SQL Task] Error: Failed to acquire connection "targetCon2". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.**

I went through many links but nothing worked for me so starting a new thread. I checked [SQL Agent Job - Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687084/sql-agent-job-connection-may-not-be-configured-correctly-or-you-may-not-have-t)

[SSIS package fail due to 'acquire connection' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957391/ssis-package-fail-due-to-acquire-connection-error)

[SSIS Package failing with "Failed to acquire connection" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119867/ssis-package-failing-with-failed-to-acquire-connection-error)

My distributed transaction service is running. DTC settings are correct. I am executing everything sequentially. Don't know whats wrong. I want to execute whole part in one transaction.

Please check the screenshots for more details.
[image: Project Snap and Error]

Comment: Right click on `targetcon2` - go to edit - at bottom left, click test connection. Is it connecting ?

Comment: Yes..it's connecting. I'm able to execute single task.

Comment: did you try this link's solution : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0a14ea20-ceac-46af-aa5c-3dd055f1da6b/error-unable-to-enlist-in-the-transaction-in-ssis-package-with-oracle-11g?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Also try once by changing `TransactionOption` to 'required'

Comment: Yes @PrabhatG I have tried. Nothing happened.

Comment: @Pravvy For the DropForeignKeys, post the screenshot of the Execute SQL Task editor and it's associated connection manager.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this issue as well. My problem was i had switched out the params file to point to a new environment. While the ADO connection 'test connection' button worked; when running the package it failed. I rebuilt the soution and it worked great after that.

Comment: Michael, can you be more specific what do you have rebuild in the solution?

Comment: @Erikhoeven Michael meant he re built the Entire SSIS Solution.